# Display time in a certain format Javascript (h:mm:ss a)

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

How I would go about displaying the time in a certain format (h:mm:ss a)? I can find examples for (hh:mm:ss a).

E.g of (h:mm:ss a)
9:10:23 PM

E.g of (hh:mm:ss a)
09:10:23 PM

EDIT:
I achieved this my question with the following:

```
<i>var formatTime = (function () {

    return function (dt) {
        var formatted = '';

        if (dt) {
            var hours24 = dt.getHours();
            var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 1;
            formatted = [formatted, [hours, addZero(dt.getMinutes())].join(":"), hours24 > 11 ? "PM" : "AM"].join(" ");            
        }

        return formatted;
    }
})();

alert(formatTime(new Date())); </i>
```

Comment: By using a time/date library. Or, take the example you found and modify it.

Comment: Or use library routines such as `toLocaleDateString()`, or `Intl.DateTimeFormat`.